# Set Codeigniter Session in Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I need to set session in Jquery but when i try it does not work
this is i am doing in jquery

```
      var a = 22;
      <?php  $this->session->set_userdata('friend_id' ,a )?>
```

it gives me syntax error, anyone knows how to solve it.

Comment: you cannot insert into a var php a var javascript/jquery, PHP is server side javascript/jquery is clienti side

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You cannot pass a jQuery/javascript variable to PHP. PHP is run on the server before transmitting, jQuery/javascript is run client side. You should look into AJAX as the solution to your problem.

Comment: there is no way to solve this?

Comment: you can make an ajax @AyshaAli

Comment: actually i am getting some data in me function so i want to set that data into that

Comment: its mean ajax call will solve this,, ok thanks i will do this by ajax call thanks.....

Comment: You should've learned how does PHP actually work before you started using frameworks such as ci.

Comment: @Mike Burnwood I thought there may be some way that i dont know so i ask it here

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use hidden field to do this

```
      <input type="hidden" value="" name="id" id="id" />
```

this will in your js

```
      var a = 22;
      document.getElementById('id').value = a;
```

hope this will help you to solve your problem, but you can't set session in Jquery

Comment: @Alessandro Minoccheri this is only way that i used in my project to solve my problem, because i just need on information from receiving data so first i try to use session bt when i can't do it then i use this method, so i advice Aysha Ali to do this and she also have done this before my answer is posted, as she say.

Comment: But the question is another.. how to set session... in your code you don't set any session

Comment: @Alessandro Minoccheri u r right bt as u told and many of others told that this is not possible to set session so only this way is helpful to solve problem

Answer (score 6):

in jquery you can do this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'test.php',
  data: '{"var":"yourvar"}',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log("Success!!");
  },
  error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
    console.log('error');
  }
});
```

and after into your file test.php

```
<?php  $this->session->set_userdata('friend_id' ,$_POST['var'] )?>
```

[MANUAL](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: This seems to be an answer to the question that was apparently asked. Win a few, lose a few.